# Typescript: Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get a error from Typescript and I am not sure how to correct it. The code works fine when "compiled" but I can't correct the error. I have extracted the parts that involve the error from my code. I guess I have to predifine the src but not sure how.

Error msg in Editor and on Gulp compile:

***"Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.at line 53 col 17"***

```
...

element:HTMLElement; /* Defining element */

'''
this.element = document.createElement('img'); /*creating a img*/

'''
```

This is the method I run to render the element, position, top and left all works with out giving a error.

```
display() {
   this.element.src = this.file; /*This is the line that gives the error*/
   this.element.style.position = "absolute";
   this.element.style.top = this.pointX.toString() + "px";
   this.element.style.left = this.pointY.toString() + "px";

   document.body.appendChild(this.element);
};
```

Comment: Effectively, `HTMLElement.prototype` doesn't have `src`, but `HTMLImageElement.prototype` should. I have no idea about TypeScript, but try defining `element` as `HTMLImageElement` instead of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: `this.element.setAttribute("src",this.file);` will work either.

Comment: @c-smile Even though I don't think your answer is the correct solution i do appreciate the notice on a different way to handle the issue

Comment: In case you were using an `iframe` instead of an `img` and the title for this question lured you in, yes, [same deal](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmliframeelement.html): `const myIframe: HTMLIFrameElement = element as HTMLIFrameElement;`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `src` is not a property of the `HTMLElement` type, but of `HTMLImageElement`.

If you are certain you'll get an img element, you might want to declare your variable with the correct subtype:

```
element: HTMLImageElement; /* Defining element */

// ...

this.element = document.createElement('img'); /*creating a img*/
```

Also, you might want to have a look at what `document.createElement` returns. It's the very same type if you specify `"img"` as its argument.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my issue, I just assumed HTMLElement was a generic DOM element that fitted all.

Comment: And your assumption was completely right. A `HTMLImageElement` is in-fact a `HTMLElement` as well. More precisely, it is a subtype. But not all elements contain an `src` attribute, hence a reason for subtyping in this case.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification

Answer (score 36):

Using casting:

```
(<HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector(".company_logo")).src
```

Answer (score 20):

```
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' );
```

Set source through set attribute method.

Answer (score 13):

go with:

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myId') as HTMLImageElement;
myImg.src = "imgSrc";
```

Comment: If you could you put more explanation to answer it will be helpful.

Comment: As you see, 'src' property doesn't exist on a normal 'HTMLElement' type. So define your element as HTMLImageElement and now you have 'src' property.

Answer (score 4):

**We can solve it with this two ways..**

**CASE - 1**

Use **`<HTMLImageElement>`** before `document.getElementById('myId')`

```
var myImg = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myId');

myImg.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300';
```

**CASE - 2**

Use **`setAttribute`** to set **`src`** to the `image` as below

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myId');

myImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300');
```

Comment: Very very thanks,
var myImg = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myId');
Works for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it as `HTMLImageElement`, which has an `src` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the target element from the event to HTMLImageElement before accessing any IMG attribute (React/Typescript example):

```
onError={
    (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement, Event>) => (
        (e.target as HTMLImageElement).src = DEFAULT_AVATAR
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using casting like @whereDatApp.com suggested worked for me. Using query selector like this:

```
querySelector("img[name='menubanner']")
```